# Windows keeps crashing when trying to install PyTorch via pip

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

I am currently trying to install PyTorch (using the installation commands posted on PyTorch.org for pip) and when I run the command, my computer completely freezes.

I tried this multiple times with the same result. I had to restart the computer a few times as well. On my current try, I put "-v" when trying to install and the pip seems to be stuck on
"Looking up  in the cache".

I do not know how to proceed. As I mentioned, I've already tried this method multiple times. It worked the first time but did not install PyTorch as it gave me an error for not using "--user".

Are there any solutions to this?

EDIT: I did want to add that I have Python 3.8.6 (64bit)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After troubling shooting and a lot of restart, it seems like the issue came from when pip was trying to load a pre-downloaded file. Essentially, the first time I ran the installation command, pip downloaded files for pytorch but did not install pytorch due to some user privilege issue. The fix is to add `--no-cache-dir` in the pip install command. This will override the cache (pre-downloaded files) and download the files all over again.

For me specifically, I also needed to add `--user`.

In other words, the command went from

```
pip install torch===1.7.0+cu110 torchvision===0.8.1+cu110 torchaudio===0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

to

```
pip --no-cache-dir install torch===1.7.0+cu110 torchvision===0.8.1+cu110 torchaudio===0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html --user
```

Answer (score 1):

As a solution, manually delete the folder C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pip\cache